# How to use card token on stripe.handleCardPayment(clientSecret[, data])

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am trying to pass a credit card token provided by the stripe payment gateway to the function stripe.handleCardPayment(clientSecret[, data]).
In the documentation [https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference] it says it's supposed to be integrated like card[token], and the token will be automatically converted into a PaymentMethod.
But how do I implement this part of code into my code?
I tried it like this but it hasn't worked...

```
            stripe.handleCardPayment(
              clientSecret,
              {
                payment_method_data: {
                    card[token]: the_card_token
                }
              }
            ).then(function(result) {
              console.log(result);
            });
```

At one point at trying I received this error:

```
A Card token may not be passed in as a PaymentMethod. Instead, use payment_method_data with type=card and card[token]=tok_xxxxxx
```

Comment: Although not exactly clear, it looks like in addition to `card[token]`, they want you to pass `type: 'card'` as well with the `payment_method_data` object. I don't see that in the docs explicitly though.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `card[token]: the_card_token`, pass it as `card: { token: 'tok_visa' }`

Something like this should work

```
stripe.handleCardPayment(client_secret, {
        payment_method_data: {
            card: {
                token: 'tok_visa'
            },
        }
    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
});
```